# Error : You must enter a value

Tags: page-layout, error, required-field

All users in my org are getting below error for required fields inspite of filling required fields using **magnifying glass lookup icon** and trying to save a record on a **Standard Pagelayout**.

These two lookup fields are **required on field level**

There are **no validation rules** on this object and user's profile has **read,create,edit,view all** permission on custom object

> Error: You must enter a value

[image: ERROR IMAGE]

Comment: Those are lookup fields, are there records on those related objects that correspond with the values you are trying to enter?

Comment: yes there are records on those related objects with the values

Comment: Did you select them using the magnifying glass lookup icon or just entered the text?

Comment: Yes I did selected using magnifying glass lookup icon

Comment: Ok, how about is this a standard page or custom VF page? Are these fields required via the page layout or required in the object model? Are there any workflows or processes on this object that would adjust those fields?

Comment: Required on field level

Comment: @sf.dev you didnt answer the rest of CyberJus's questions

Comment: @Phil B It's a standard page layout.required on field level and there are no workflow or processes on that object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.There was a Before Insert trigger on custom object which was auto populating Contact,Building  from Case and when the Contact or building is blank on Case  we are getting this error.